# Script will not download files when called by cron or udev rules

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, udev

So I'm trying to make a script that will download my podcasts upon detecting my smart watch connecting and transfer them to it. I've configured the udev rule to detect when the watch is connected and it executes /bin/watch_transfer.sh for which the code is as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "Watch connected at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log

# Download new podcasts
cd /home/pi/Scripts/
./bashpodder.shell >>/tmp/pscripts.log

echo "Upodder should've run by now">>/tmp/scripts.log

# Transfer podcasts
for file in /home/pi/Downloads/podcasts/*
 do
  /usr/bin/mtp-sendfile $file /Podcasts
  echo "Processing $file" >>/tmp/scripts.log
 done

echo "Sent all files" >>/tmp/scripts.log
```

I know that the file runs when the watch is connected because /tmp/scripts.log is created and updated, and also bashpodder.shelll creates the podcast.m3u file so the bashpodder script is running but it doesn't download any files to /~/Downloads/podcasts. Bashpodder is a simle podcast downloader (I was using [upodder](https://github.com/topics/podcast-downloader) but switched because it didn't seem to work) and [mtp-tools is a way to transfer files through MTP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/mtp-tools.1.html). Bashpodder.shell script below:

```
# By Linc 10/1/2004
# Find the latest script at http://lincgeek.org/bashpodder
# Revision 1.21 12/04/2008 - Many Contributers!
# If you use this and have made improvements or have comments
# drop me an email at linc dot fessenden at gmail dot com
# and post your changes to the forum at http://lincgeek.org/lincware
# I'd appreciate it!

# Make script crontab friendly:
cd $(dirname $0)

# datadir is the directory you want podcasts saved to:
datadir=/home/pi/Downloads/podcasts

# create datadir if necessary:
mkdir -p $datadir

# Delete any temp file:
rm -f temp.log

# Read the bp.conf file and wget any url not already in the podcast.log file:
while read podcast
        do
        file=$(xsltproc parse_enclosure.xsl $podcast 2> /dev/null || wget -q $podcast -O - | tr '\r' '\n' | tr \' \" | sed -n 's/.*url="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p')
        for url in $file
                do
                echo $url >> temp.log
                if ! grep "$url" podcast.log > /dev/null
                        then
                        wget -t 10 -U BashPodder -c -q -O $datadir/$(echo "$url" | awk -F'/' {'print $NF'} | awk -F'=' {'print $NF'} | awk -F'?' {'print $1'}) "$url"
                fi
                done
        done < bp.conf
# Move dynamically created log file to permanent log file:
cat podcast.log >> temp.log
sort temp.log | uniq > podcast.log
rm temp.log
# Create an m3u playlist:
ls $datadir | grep -v m3u > $datadir/podcast.m3u
```

I think it might be something to do with permissions? As when I run ./watch_transfer.sh from the terminal it runs perfectly. Thanks in advance for your help.

edit:
After connecting my watch:

Ouput of $ cat /tmp/scripts.log:

```
Watch connected at Thu Jul 16 22:25:47 BST 2020
Upodder should've run by now
Processing /home/pi/Downloads/podcasts/podcast.m3u
Sent all files
```

$ cat /tmp/psripts.log doesn't output anything but /tmp/pscripts.log does exist.

Output of $ cat ~/Scripts/temp.log:

```
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20060108.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20051020.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20051017.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20050807.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20050719.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20050615.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20050525.mp3
http://rasterweb.net/raster/audio/rwaudio20050323.mp3
```

This seems to suggest that bashpodder is running through the urls but not actually downloading them?

Comment: Please include any relevant information from the error log, and preferably verify that errors are correctly logged by adding e.g. `ls /doesnotexist` and verify that the message "cannot access '/doesnotexist': No such file or directory" can be found in the log (to ensure that the error log actually contains errors)

Comment: @thatotherguy Added the output of the log files, I'll try to add ls /doesnotexist now

Comment: Your permissions thought is likely correct. Not the `rwx` permissions themselves, but the name of the user. `cron` runs as a different user (often `cron`). If `udev` is providing access for user `pi`, it may very well reject user `cron` for that same access on security grounds. I'm not familiar with the Pi udev setup, but with the default user fixed as `pi`, it wouldn't surprise me if something like user-permissions were the issue. That's where I would start my search. Others may know exactly. [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) may be more on point.

Comment: I'm not aware of any system in which cron jobs run as `nobody` instead of the owner of the crontab. Do you have an example?

Comment: Not off hand. I recall that from a cron issue more than a decade ago on the SuSE list. Changed to `cron` -- but honestly, whatever user is used that ain't `pi` is what is relevant here.

Comment: @olibpool : Since your script is not be executed by bash, please remove the _bash_ tag from your question.

Comment: @user1934428 I put the bash tag because the scripts are written in Bash and I didn't know whether my problem was with the code, should I still remove the tag?

Comment: @olibpool: It does not. Your script has a shebang line, from which I assume that you invoke the script by providing just the script name (and arguments), and don't write `bash` explicitly. But your line is `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, so it is not bash. From within, you are sourcing `bashpodder.shell`, but since the source then is `sh` instead of `bash`, `bashpodder` also won't be interpreted by bash.

Comment: @user1934428 ah I see. As you can probably tell I'm fairly new to this stuff lol.